# macro not Click "href" link in website VBA code

Tags: html, excel, vba

I want to execute one code from Excel that it open the invoice search window from website. i got the code but macro is not clicking on the "href" and also not giving any kind of error.could you please help me to resolve the issue.

```
Sub ExceltoHTML()    
Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim ies As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDOC As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLINPUT As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLAS As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLA As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
 ie.Visible = True
 ie.Navigate "https://travelex-prod.proactisp2p.com/ClassicP2P/Invoicing/Home.aspx"

Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Loop

Set HTMLDOC = ie.Document
Set HTMLAS = HTMLDOC.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each HTMLA In HTMLAS
'Debug.Print HTMLA.getAttribute("Classname"), HTMLA.getAttribute("href"), HTMLA.getAttribute("rel")

If HTMLA.getAttribute("href")="https://travelexprod.proactisp2p.com/ClassicP2P/Invoicing/Plus/ViewInvoiceSearch.aspx" Then
    HTMLA.Click
End If
```

Comment: Does the link definitely exist in that page?

Comment: To investigate what @TimWilkinson suggested, put a break point on `HTMLA.Click` line and run your code. If it doesn't stop at that point then either the link doesn't exist on the page or maybe you have miss typed the URL

Comment: Do you have to log in to get to the site you're trying to get the attribute of?

Comment: Yes, the link is correct only. i got it in Element inspect.

Comment: @BruceWayne, yes i have to login first then i need to run macro

Comment: @Zac, could you please elaborate your answer? i haven't understand your answer

Comment: In the VBA editor select the line `HTMLA.Click` and create a break line (F9), then run your entire code and see if it stops on that line.

Comment: i came to know that, the macro is disabling all the hyperlinks once the page loaded, that's what it is not clicking the button.. is there any other solution?

Comment: Yes, it is stopping at that step